# How do I create a Windows 10 gold image that is sys-prepped without using a virtual machine manager?

Tags: windows-10

I want to create a Windows 10 image for deployment to 50 computers.

Is it possible to use a pre-built computer out of the box to create a baseline Windows 10 copy pre-loaded with required software, sysprep it and then make an image out of that? What software can I use to do this and how do I go about this process?

Comment: To get an image that I can use to install Windows 10 on another computer with software pre-loaded. I want to sysprep it as part of that process is what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two separate steps are required to accomplish this:

1. Sysprep the image
2. Clone the image to other computers

There's not a single program that does both, since Sysprep is already available as a standalone utility. For the second step, use whatever disk cloning software you prefer--it doesn't matter as long as it's doing its job of cloning the disk as-is.

A word of caution: You can only Sysprep an install once, so if your pre-built machine was installed from a Sysprepped image, then you can't Sysprep it a second time. In this case you need to start with a fresh installation of Windows that you make yourself.

Because of this limitation it's common to duplicate the master installation of Windows and run Sysprep on the *duplicate* to prepare it for deployment. The original is sometimes called the "Gold image." That way in the future you can make changes to the Gold image, duplicate it again, and run Sysprep on the new duplicate image, and repeat the process as many times as needed.